# Accessing external javascript code in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file, external

I have a script block in my ASP.Net file, where I should access javascript of an external control. This doesn't seem to work at all, I tried all the solutions I found on the web, but probably I'm not searching for the right stuff. As far as I've seen the `src` attribute in the script tag would do the work, but I can't have own code and this `src` attribute it seems.

Interesting enough, it works proper when I just call the javascript function from the event. Something like this:

Works:

```
<stgwc:ImageLinkButton runat="server" ID="ImageLinkButton1" ImageUrl="~/Images/base/Icons/16x16/brush1.png" OnClientClick="GridRowEnterEditMode(this, 'EditRole'); return false;" />
```

And my approach was:

```
<stgwc:ImageLinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEditRole" ImageUrl="~/Images/base/Icons/16x16/brush1.png" OnClientClick="EnterRolesEditMode(this.id); return false;" />

function EnterRolesEditMode(btnClientId) {
    var grd = document.getElementById('dgrRoles');
    var btn = document.getElementById(btnClientId);
    grd.GridRowEnterEditMode(btn, 'EditRole');
}
```

Comment: There may be several things wrong here.  Do you get any errors on the JavaScript console in your browser?  For example, does `this.id` have the value you expect?  It looks like you don't even need `this.id` since all you do with it is `document.getElementById(value)`.  You can just pass `this` and skip that step.

Comment: Hello, yeah this.id gets me the id of the button? I need to do this since I access this function from the code behind as well. Ofc I could make 2 functions, but I dont think it solves the error since I get the response the GridRowEnterEditMode is unknown.

Comment: Where is `GridRowEnterEditMode` defined?  You're trying to call it on a DOM element, which probably isn't correct.  Based on the naming convention, it looks like a server-side function.  If that's the case then JavaScript can't call it directly.

Comment: Hello, the GridRowEnterEditMode is a Javascript function definied in the external control javaScript.

Comment: Hello there, sorry for double post: I dont need object.Function, just calling the function is enought. I'm quite unsure what will happen if i define more than one dataGrid object per ASP.Net page but in this case it works fine.
Thanks for the help so far!